# Using IR Sensor to sense movement?

Tags: arduino-uno, ir

I was wondering if I could use a IR sensor with my Arduino to detect if someone is present in front of it.

Like, the emitter should emit continuously and if the receiver drop connection it should do something.

Will this work fine? or the emitter wide angle and a human body in front of it wont drop the signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work fine. The easiest way to do this is using **IR Sensor Module**.

[image]

This will give you a digital output of whether there is someone in front of sensor or not. Use can use it as an Edge Trigger to detect Humans passing by.

You can buy one. They are both cheap and easily available.

Or you can [create your own](http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Infrared-Sensor-Module/).

Answer (score 0):

This works quite fine !
The "hardest" part is isolating the IR beam and especially the receiver with anti-reflective paint or paper (ie : a small hole in a cardboard)

You can make this by two (at least) ways :

- [IRled]         [human]          [IRreceiver]
- [IRled and receiver pointing the same way]       [human]        [mirror]

The second way is what you find in auto-flushing toilet rooms. But if the human is wearing quite reflective clothes, this will fool the receiver.
This is great for long-range detection, but if you need a smaller range, go for the 1/.